# SQL Server chaining with CTE

Tags: sql-server, chaining

```
ID  MatchID phone MPhone  date    Mdate
-----------------------------------------
C1  C2     1234   1234   5-Jan    1-Jan
C2  C3     1234   1234   1-Jan    3-Jan
C3  C4     1234   1234   3-Jan    4-Jan
```

i have a data set as shown above and i am trying to find the master record based on phone number. if we look at the data C1= c2= c3=c4 based on phone numbers. Based on Mdate (recent date is 5-jan ,so C1 is the master record). i was trying with cte to filter the master record,joining based on C1.phone=C2.Mphone. Any help with the Select query would be appreciated

```
output
ID  phone   date  Type  
-----------------------------------------
C1  1234    5-Jan   M
C2  1234    1-jan   NM
C3  1234    3-jan   NM
c4  1234    4-Jan   NM
```

`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i am planning to get the data into a temp table with a flag identifier to differentiate master and other records. Thank you.In this case output would be C1, 1234,5-jan,'Master'

Comment: Sorry , i was answering by mistake hit the enter key.

Comment: You are looking for a recursive hierarchical query.  Are the chains guaranteed to be a certain max length?

Comment: no, in certain case c5 or c6 ids can exists. if c6 has the recent date then only that should be filtered as Master

Comment: It'd really help to see sample output

Comment: Sorry,I have edited the question  by correcting the dates and output

Comment: Can an entity have multiple parents? Can C1 be parented by C2 and C3? Can you have multiple children? Can C3 parent both C2 and C1? If the answer to either previous question is yes, how is that represented in your result set?

Comment: we are using the datetime column to avoid conflict.therefore there will be only one record will have latest datetime.Multiple parent scenario should be avoided based on date time. yes rest all records can be considered as children.thx

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need CTE to achieve this.  Please check the following query:

```
declare @table table 
    (ID nvarchar(50),  MatchID nvarchar(50), phone nvarchar(50), 
     MPhone nvarchar(50), [date] nvarchar(50), Mdate nvarchar(50));

insert into @table values
('C1','C2','1234','1234','5-Jan','1-Jan'),
('C2','C3','1234','1234','1-Jan','3-Jan'),
('C3','C4','1234','1234','3-Jan','4-Jan');

SELECT ID, phone, [date], MatchID, 
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT MatchID from @table as b where b.MatchID = a.ID) 
          THEN 'NM' 
          ELSE 'M' 
       END as [Type]
  FROM @table as a;

/* OUTPUT

ID phone date  MatchID Type
-- ----- ----- ------- ----
C1 1234  5-Jan C2      M
C2 1234  1-Jan C3      NM
C3 1234  3-Jan C4      NM

*/
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve the chaining problem. It just says "there is another record with the same ID" not explicitly "there is a record which, through any sequence of other IDs is this record's parent". I believe, as stated above, an rCTE is the correct approach here.

Comment: Agree with you Xedni,a recursive cte is what we are looking for,thank you

Comment: @Ims you need to provide a different set of sample data.  Given the sample data provided this solution does solve the problem as posted.